# Mypy loses type of the TypedDict when unpacked

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have the following code when trying to spread the dictionary
from typing import TypedDict

```
class MyDict(TypedDict):
    foo: int

def test(inp: MyDict):
    m: MyDict = inp # OK
    n: MyDict = {**inp} # <-- ERROR
```

I receive an error `Expression of type "dict[str, object]" cannot be assigned to declared type`

Any idea how can I preserve the type after spread?

Comment: Is `inp.copy()` an option for you instead of unpacking? It preserves type.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, neither **mypy** nor **pyright** is smart enough to infer the type of an unpacked `dict`. See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4122.

As a workaround use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```py
from typing import cast, TypedDict


class MyDict(TypedDict):
    foo: int


def test(inp: MyDict):
    m: MyDict = inp # OK
    n: MyDict = cast(MyDict, {**inp}) # OK
```